# The buttons present withing the HANDLEBARS templates are not firing the events

Tags: jquery, html, handlebars.js

I was trying to provide the click event to the buttons present in the handlebars template. But the events are not getting fired. Please find the code below:

### TEMPLATE

```
<table class="table shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">NAME</th>
            <th scope="col">EMAIL</th>
            <th scope="col">DOB</th>
            <th scope="col">DEPT</th>
            <th scope="col">GENDER</th>
            <th scope="col">AGE</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each ALL_RECORDS}}
          <tr>
            <td scope="row">{{this.name}}</td>
            <td scope="row">{{this.eMail}}</td>
            <td scope="row">{{this.DOB}}</td>
            <td scope="row">{{this.dept}}</td>
            <td scope="row">{{this.gender}}</td>
            <td scope="row">{{this.age}}</td>
            <th scope="row" style="text-align: center"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="EDIT_BTN">EDIT</button></th>
            <th scope="row" style="text-align: center"><button class="btn btn-danger"  type="button" name="DEL_BTN">DELETE</button></th>   
          </tr>
          {{/each}}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

### Jquery

```
$("[name='DEL_BTN']").click(function(){
    alert("DELETE BUTTON CLICKED");
})
```

Here on clicking the delete button, it's not firing the alert.
Same button when moved out of the template to HTML page, it is working fine. Can you please help me in this..??

Comment: likely your button doesn't exist at the time you are binding the event try delegating the event from a parent element thats not being generated by handlebars eg: $('.table').on('click', 'button' , function(e){ //do stuff });

Comment: @digital-pollution That worked. Thank you so much....

Answer (score 1):

Try to add $(document).ready() around your function so that your template will be rendered and inserted into DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("[name='DEL_BTN']").click(function(){
       alert("DELETE BUTTON CLICKED");
   })
});
```

I think that your problem is that the event is not binded to your button at the moment you launch the jquery function. If you don't want to use the $(document).ready method just make sure your handlebar template has been evaluated and inserted into the DOM before using your selector and launching your alert.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have already tried adding the $(document).ready but still the button click even is not working. Can you please help me. I was completely stuck here...

Comment: @METALHEAD First in your console have you tried to console.log($("[name='DEL_BTN']")); at the same time that you try to add your click event ?

Comment: While tried to console, I am getting output as this `w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
length:0
prevObject:w.fn.init [document]
__proto__:Object(0)`

Comment: Try this $("[name='DEL_BTN']").each(function(a,b){console.log(b);}) this should display your html code for the button. If it display nothing that means that your template is not inserted in the DOM yet. If it is not inserted yet then you'll have to explain how you render your template and then you'll have to move your code after your template has been rendered.

Comment: Thanks @christophie for all the guidance. I've used delegates for resolving this. Thank you.